# ImportError when importing matplotlib in my conda environment: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, python-imaging-library, conda

I'm new in the field, so sorry for possible silly mistakes.
I'm working with snakemake, so I created a conda environment following their directions:

```
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
mamba create -c conda-forge -c bioconda -n snakemake snakemake
```

However, while I was running the basic tutorial ([enter link description here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html#step-7-adding-a-target-rule)) a ModuleNotFoundError occurred:

```
snakemake --cores 1
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

For this reason, I've installed matplotlib with conda-forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

However, when I re-runned the tutorial, I got an ImportError:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/**init**.py)
> So I decided to install in the same conda environment also pillow:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pillow
```

But I obtain the same error running the tutorial.

All of the imported packages are coming from my conda environment:

> ```
> anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages
> ```

Besides the path of PIL/pillow which is imported from:

> usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

I also update conda, anaconda and all of the packages present in my snakemake environment. Moreover, I checked the presence of PIL with conda list and it is actualy present in my snakemake environment with the same path of other packages (anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages).

I've noticed that in other issues it is suggested to uninstall and re install Pillow.
Howeever, when I try to uninstall:

```
pip uninstall Pillow
```

and

```
pip3 uninstall Pillow
```

I obtain:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permesso negato: 'BlpImagePlugin.cpython-38.pyc'

Therefore I've tried to force the upgrade:

```
pip install -U Pillow --user
```

and

```
pip3 install -U Pillow --user
```

And the terminal states that I have succesfully installed Pillow 8.0.1. However, when I import matplotlib the same error occurs:

> > ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/**init**.py)

I'm grateful for any hints
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved uninstalling from the system PIL package:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pil
```

I still do not know why it works, but at least now I can use properly matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed a part in the setup for the tutorial (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/setup.html). In step 2, you download an environment.yaml and use it to install all needed packages. Or you could try and install all packages yourself, look at the list under "Requirements".

Comment: Hi jafors, thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, I've tried such installation steps present in the tutorial in my first try (each of the step, beside the once for windows operating systems); however, following those installation steps lead to the same error regarding pillow